# Edit the Userpoint Total Section

Tags: views, userpoints

I have 3 userpoint categories: *Points*, *Fines* and *Bonus*. I'd like the *Total* category to only track the *Points* and *Fines* category, while the other *Bonus* category is tracked separately.

I know the Category ID number, used in the database, for each separate category if that can the process any easier.

Is there anyway to edit what factors into the *Total (all categories)* section on Userpoints?